# "Brought dead"—mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

He was shifted to hospital where doctors said he was brought dead.

The word "Dead" is a "adverb" or "adjective" in the sentence? Is the sentence is correct syntactically and natural???

Comment: 'Brought dead' sounds like some kind of local expression. Where did you see this?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey On a Indian newspaper

Comment: The sentence doesn't make sense to me. It's not correct or natural. There is also a problem with she/he. It would seem the writter can't make up their mind which gender the patient is. Please provide more of the quote - context might help. Are you sure that you quoted it correctly?  Have you considered that it might also just be an error. Even journalists can make mistakes.

Comment: @BillyKerr I have made a correction.

Comment: Yes, I see you have now changed "she" to "he".  Please check your source again, and provide more of the quotation, the surrounding paragraph. Provide a link to the article if possible.

Comment: @BillyKerr this is the link:—https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.outlookindia.com/website/story/where-kashmir-doctor-learned-it-was-his-son-brought-dead/312956/amp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"dead" is an adjective and functions to complete the clause headed by "brought".  It describes the patient, so it is an adjective. It doesn't function to modify the verb like an adverb.

It's not the usual idiomatic expression, which is "dead on arrival" (or DOA). This is likely an Indian dialect usage.

Answer (score 2):

You have misquoted the article.  Here is what it actually says.

> Dr Poswal certified that he was ‘brought dead’. He then wrapped the
> body in white cloth and started crying.

Then later there is another quote from another doctor

> I express my gratitude to many doctors and paramedics in addition to
> those who were on roster duty for staying beyond their official time
> to help the injured in yesterday's encounter. Their services on the
> ground made a difference as all injured were stabilized and treated
> but unfortunately, our doctor colleague’s son was received brought
> dead where we all became helpless

Source: [Outlook India](https://www.outlookindia.com/website/story/where-kashmir-doctor-learned-it-was-his-son-brought-dead/312956)

The quotation marks around the first quote are an important detail which you missed.

This seems to be a quotation of what someone said at the time.  From the context it seems it means the patient was "dead on arrival", or more literally "brought there dead", i.e. "brought to the hospital already dead".

This is not something used in other English speaking countries. It might be acceptable in Indian English, but I'm no expert in that subject. However it isn't standard in English, generally.

In the UK we would say the patient was "dead on arrival" or "already dead".

Just one more thing to note here. That last sentence is all quite strange to me.  I'm not sure if this is really standard in Indian English either. It sounds distinctly non-native. Of course not even all native English speakers are skilled in writing, and errors do happen.

> our doctor colleague’s son was received brought dead where we all
> became helpless